# Dropdown/Select in Angular4

Tags: angular, typescript, semantic-ui, angularfire2, selectize.js

I'm working on an AngularFire2 Project using Angular 4.2.4 and the Angular CLI 1.1.3 and am new to TypeScript. In multiple components I need to use searchable dropdowns/tagging like can be seen [here](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) and [here](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#search-dropdown).

I can't get any of the .js files to run when I link to them in the index.html file like so:

```
<script src="assets/semantic-ui-dropdown/dropdown.js"></script>
```

From what I've been able to find, this either has to do with the typescript definitions or something wrong with how I've included JQuery (just a script tag in index.html). After following a lot of other threads, I have absolutely no idea how to get this working. Do I need to import something in the component? My goal is to be able to use classes in the html document, as the angular 4+ versions of these are not available yet (as far as I know).

Comment: [This might Help](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/#/faq). There is a question solely dedicated on how to import third party JS in Angular . You can do it with typings or without your choice and for popular libs typings will be available